# Count up Char values

Tags: java

For example: I want to make a simple Scrabble game. Im typing in a word, i will get each character apart and give it a value. I want to count up this values but it just won't work. In the result it shows that the characters each got their value but don't count up.

This is my code:

```
`public class StringBodyBuilder {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    char character;
    String word;
    int wordValue =0;

    System.out.print("Give a word: ");
    word = scanner.nextLine();

    for (int i = 0; i <word.length() ; i++) {
        character = word.toLowerCase().charAt(i);
        wordValue =+ character;

        switch (character) {
            case 'a' :
            case 'e' :
            case 'i' :
            case 'n' :
            case 'o' : System.out.println(1);
                break;
            case 'd' :
            case 'r' :
            case 's' :
            case 't' : System.out.println(2);
                break;
            case 'b' :
            case 'g' :
            case 'k' :
            case 'l' :
            case 'm' :
            case 'p' : System.out.println(3);
                break;
            case 'f' :
            case 'h' :
            case 'j' :
            case 'u' :
            case 'v' : System.out.println(4);
                break;
            case 'c' :
            case 'w' : System.out.println(5);
                break;
            case 'x' :
            case 'y' : System.out.println(8);
                break;
            case 'q' : System.out.println(10);
                break;
            case ' ' : System.out.println(0);
                break;
        }

        System.out.println(wordValue);
    }
}
```

Result:
Give a word: cow
5
99
1
111
5
119

Comment: Don't print them. Add them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only printing the values of the letters but not actually using them.

For example you could save the values like this:

```
int value = 0;

switch (character) {
    case 'a' :
    case 'e' :
    case 'i' :
    case 'n' :
    case 'o' : 
        value = 1;
        break;
    case 'd' :
    case 'r' :
    case 's' :
    case 't' : 
        value = 2;
        break;
    ...
```

and after the switch:

```
wordValue += value;   // += and not =+
System.out.println(wordValue);
```